# Null Pointer Exception Error While Execute Selenium Test Case

Tags: java, selenium, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests

I'm Beginner For Selenium Java Programming. When I'm Executing Below Script With TestNG I Face An Error.

Error Message

> "java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke
> "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By)"
> because "this.driver" is null"

```
Please Check Below Code And Suggest Changes.

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;

public class RegForm {
        
    public WebDriver driver; 
    
    @BeforeTest
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D://Selenium//ChromeDriver//chromedriver");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://automationpractice.com/index.php");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    }
        
    @Test
    public void TC01() throws Exception {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"header\"]/div[2]/div/div/nav/div[1]/a")).click();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        
    }

}
```

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67145532/cannot-invoke-org-openqa-selenium-webdriver-findelementorg-openqa-selenium-by

Comment: I guess you should mention D://Selenium//ChromeDriver//chromedriver.exe

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `WebDriver` from the `main` try as below

```
public static WebDriver driver; 
@BeforeTest
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D://Selenium//ChromeDriver//chromedriver");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://automationpractice.com/index.php");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
}
```

If you are not using MAC then try to provide the chromedriver extension `.exe`, Also check the import for the `@Test` as you mentioned you are using `testng`

Answer (score 0):

Creating a driver in a test class is not the best idea.

It may be a good idea to implement something similar to [this](https://www.vinsguru.com/selenium-webdriver-design-patterns-in-test-automation-factory-pattern/)

Answer (score 0):

Had  the same issue wasted 1 full day in it.
Please check if you have defined web driver in any other class or not.
if yes then make it protected and extent it with this class.

```
protected static WebDriver driver;
```